# insert text inside a line

Tags: c, fgets, file-handling

I have a file pointer which I am using with fgets() to give me a complete line along with the new line in the buffer.
I want to replace 1 char and add another character before the new line.  Is that possible? 
For example:

```
buffer is "12345;\n"
output buffer is "12345xy\n"
```

This is the code:

```
buff = fgets((char *)newbuff, IO_BufferSize , IO_handle[i_inx]->fp);
nptr = IO_handle[i_inx]->fp;
if(feof(nptr))
    {
            memcpy((char *)o_rec_buf+(strlen((char *)newbuff)-1),"E",1);
    }
    else
    {
            memcpy((char *)o_rec_buf+(strlen((char *)newbuff)-1),"R",1);
    }
```

As you can see I am replacing the new line here (example line is shown above).
I want to insert the text and retain the new line instead of what I am doing above.

Comment: Show us some code and the problem you are facing. What you say is very much possible. However the lack of proper context won't help us help you.

Comment: Why are the casts necessary? What is the type of `newbuff` and `o_rec_buff` that makes them necessary?  You should eschew casts unless they are necessary, and it is far from obvious why they would be needed.  Also, the '`if (feof(nptr))`' test is an import from Pascal-think.  You should test the return value from `fgets()`.  Also note that the contents of the buffer are undefined if the `fgets()` call fails - that means you cannot rely on it containing anything sane.  (It probably will be the same as before the failed call, but you cannot rely on it being so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't insert one character the way you want to. If you are sure the `o_rec_buf` has enough space, and that the line will always end in `";\n"`, then you can do something like:

```
size_t n = strlen(newbuff);
if (n >= 2)
    strcpy(o_rec_buf + n - 1, "E\n");
    /* memcpy(o_rec_buf+n-1, "E\n", 3); works too */
```

Note that using `feof()` like the way you do is an error most of the times.  `feof()` tells you if you hit end-of-file condition on a file *after* you hit it.  If you are running the above code in a loop, when `feof()` returns 'true', no line will be read by `fgets`, and `buff` will be `NULL`, but `newbuff` will be unchanged.  In other words, `newbuff` will contain data from the last `fgets` call.  You will process the last line twice.  See [CLC FAQ 12.2](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html) for more, and a solution.

Finally, why all the casts?  Are `o_rec_buf` and `newbuff` not of type `char *`?

Answer (score 1):

If the buffer has enough space, you'll need to move the trailer 1 character further, using memmove and update the char you need.
Make sure you do not forget to memmove the trailing '\0'.